# ARM processor error in Genymotion

Tags: android, arm, genymotion

I am trying to run an app called DSPloit in Genymotion but whenever I run it, it displays an error message : 'It seems like your device processor is not an ARM, I'm sorry but it's not compatible with DSPloit.'

However, I have installed the zip file called Genymotion ARM Translation but there is no difference.

What should I do to get the app running?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of common issue with ARM try this link.. Hope it helps.. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: The same one I mentioned in the question.